# Find T10(x): the Taylor polynomial of degree 10

Tags: calculus

[image]

I keep thinking that all you do is plug in 0 into the problem for c0 and then solve. And then you plug in 2 for c2...and so on.

I feel dumb...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: The general form of a Taylor series about $0$ is

$$f(x) = \sum_{n= 0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n$$

The $c_n$ refers to this coefficient; that is,

$$c_n = \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$$

So for example, $f^{(0)}(0) = \frac{7x}{x + 14} |_{x = 0} = 0$. Likewise, take the first derivative to find $f^{(1)}(0)$, and so on.